# Need help solving complicated integral $\int e^{-x}\cos4x\cos2x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

I need some help solving this integral, seems nasty to me!

$$
\int e^{-x}\cos4x\cos2x\,\mathrm dx
$$

I tried integration by parts, but that seemed to me of no use.

There's also a similar one, maybe it might help solving this one or vice versa.

$$
\int x\sin x\sin 2x\sin 3x\,\mathrm dx
$$

Again, please try to give just hints...! (As I always ask :D)

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's formula?

Comment: Yes, but so far we've not used complex numbers in solving integrals. Although bring it on - let's see how useful complex numbers can be in solving such integrals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that

$$2 \cos{a x} \cos{b x} = \cos{(a-b) x} + \cos{(a+b) x}$$

and

$$\int dx\: e^{p x} \cos{q x} = \frac{p \cos{q x} + q \sin{q x}}{p^2+q^2} e^{p x} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.

Comment: Quite funny! I almost forgot about the 2nd formula!

Answer (score 1):

$\cos4x\cos2x=\frac{1}{2}(\cos6x+\cos2x)$

---

Another method is to use $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $2\cos{x}*\cos{y}=\cos{(x-y)}+\cos{(x+y)}$
Next, use integration by parts twice.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be working! Although the answer turns out to be humongous. Never mind, I got the answer at least!